# Will Jekyll import Virtuemart products as well as Joomla contnt?

Tags: joomla, static, jekyll, wget, virtuemart

I need to create static copies of some websites created in Joomla/Virtuemart combo because I want to keep the sites live but are no longer updated. Will Jekyll be able to do this with the database connection, or is there some other solution to successfully create the static copy of the full site?

Answer (score 1):

There are [a few ways](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16423/120) to create a static copy of a Joomla website but these tools only take a copy of the html that is generated on each page. This does not include any of the PHP logic of a Joomla shopping cart or a connection to the database so is probably only suitable for a truly static website without interactive features.